# Getting Activity in Service

Tags: android, android-activity, service, intentservice

I have a class `GPSTracker`

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service
```

with constructor

`public GPSTracker(Context context, Activity activity) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.activity = activity;
        getLocation();}`

Now I am in my `IntentService` called `DirtyJobSevice` and cant crate my object, because of `Activity`.

```
gps = new GPSTracker(this, ?);
```

I tried almost everything and nothing works. What should i place in "?"

Comment: are you sure you need to create service object explicitly? This is bad practice to have references on activity in the service also.

Comment: You absolutely do not want to do this.

Comment: I moved code from GPSTracker to DirtyJobService and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer to your question but don't create services explicitly. Just start them with `startService`.
use `broadcastReceiver` to communicate between services, activities

In service DirtyJobSevice you have Context so you can start another service from there I think.(not tested)